# Pretty printing JSON from Jackson 2.2's ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, jackson

Right now I have an instance of `org.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` and would like to get a `String` with pretty JSON. All of the results of my Google searches have come up with Jackson 1.x ways of doing this and I can't seem to find the proper, non-deprecated way of doing this with 2.2. Even though I don't believe that code is absolutely necessary for this question, here's what I have right now:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
System.out.println("\n\n----------REQUEST-----------");
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
mapper.writeValue(sw, jsonObject);
// Want pretty version of sw.toString() here
```

Answer (score 317, accepted):

You can enable pretty-printing by setting the `SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT` on your `ObjectMapper` like so:

```
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
```

Comment: I have also tried this but it seems that `SerializationConfig` is resolved but `SerializationConfig.Feature` is not. This seems to be another method of pretty printing that's also deprecated unless I'm missing something. There is a `Feature` class that's separated out on its own, but does not have an `INDENT_OUTPUT` constant inside. :(

Comment: Excellent! I'd love to know how you found that ;)

Comment: I looked at one of my projects, but it appears that it is also here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind under "Commonly used Features"

Comment: The relevant import needed is 
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{SerializationFeature, ObjectMapper}

Comment: on 2.2.1 this is what it took for me:   import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.Feature;
mapper.enable(Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

Comment: This did not work for with the 2.5.3 api, I've added the updated api call in my answer

Comment: ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonObject));

Answer (score 52):

According to [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/), the magic incantation is `defaultPrintingWriter` to [pretty print JSON](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-enable-pretty-print-json-output-jackson/):

Newer versions:

```
System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonInstance));
```

Older versions:

```
System.out.println(mapper.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter().writeValueAsString(jsonInstance));
```

---

Seems I jumped the gun a tad quickly. You could try [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), whose [constructor supports pretty-printing](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Compact-Vs.-Pretty-Printing-for-JSON-Output-Format):

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String jsonOutput = gson.toJson(someObject);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I found this article and was disappointed to find that this is one of those deprecated ways of pretty printing. `defaultPrettyPrintingWriter()` is no longer available (even as a deprecated method) on the `ObjectMapper` class.

Comment: I was actually thinking about doing this, but my application is already heavily Jackson-oriented and all of the functionality is actually complete. The web application server that this will be hosted on is already being taxed pretty heavily, and I wouldn't want to load extra libraries simply for logging requests and responses. I will definitely up-vote your answer, though.

Comment: @AnthonyAtkinson in Jackson 2.3 there is a method `ObjectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()`

Answer (score 41):

The jackson API has changed:

```
new ObjectMapper()
.writer()
.withDefaultPrettyPrinter()
.writeValueAsString(new HashMap<String, Object>());
```

Comment: It’s still possible (with Jackson 2.7.6) to use `new ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true).writer().writeValueAsString(new HashMap<String, Object>());`. You just have to make sure to use the writer you get from the configured `ObjectMapper`.

Answer (score 4):

the IDENT_OUTPUT did not do anything for me, and to give a complete answer that works with my jackson 2.2.3 jars:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

byte[] jsonBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\data\\testfiles\\single-line.json"));

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

Object json = objectMapper.readValue( jsonBytes, Object.class );

System.out.println( objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString( json ) );
}
```

Comment: Saved my day @Stan. Wish I could give a million upvotes !

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to turn this on by default for ALL ObjectMapper instances in a process, here's a little hack that will set the default value of INDENT_OUTPUT to true:

```
val indentOutput = SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT
val defaultStateField = indentOutput.getClass.getDeclaredField("_defaultState")
defaultStateField.setAccessible(true)
defaultStateField.set(indentOutput, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring and jackson combination you can do it as following. I'm following @gregwhitaker as suggested but implementing in spring style.

```
<bean id="objectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper">
    <property name="dateFormat">
        <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
            <constructor-arg value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
            <property name="lenient" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="serializationInclusion">
        <value type="com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include">
            NON_NULL
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <ref bean="objectMapper" />
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod">
        <value>enable</value>
    </property>
    <property name="arguments">
        <value type="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature">
            INDENT_OUTPUT
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If others who view this question only have a JSON string (not in an object), then you can put it into a `HashMap` and still get the `ObjectMapper` to work. The `result` variable is your JSON string.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

// Pretty-print the JSON result
try {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> response = objectMapper.readValue(result, HashMap.class);
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(response));
} catch (JsonParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -7):

Try this.

```
 objectMapper.enable(SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
```

Comment: Duplicating the chosen answer after 7 months is not really helpful.

Comment: might helpful to some one as i mentioned in one line,i feel good in sharing whatever i am knowing.