# New line in jackson generated xml for every sub root element

Tags: jackson-dataformat-xml

- I want to generate my xml file to be as below.

  ```xml
  <CommunicationFile count="1">
      <Communication><creationDate>2017-11-25</creationDate> ... </Communication>
      <Communication><creationDate>2017-11-25</creationDate> ... </Communication>
  </CommunicationFile>
  ```
- I need a new line for every Communication element start.
- Currently it is generating entire xml in one line. Is it possible? I
  am uing jackson 2.6.7 API's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617370/pretty-printing-json-from-jackson-2-2s-objectmapper

Comment: I tried to use like this to format :xmlMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(communicationFile); But I getting error like ,   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Underlying Stax XMLStreamWriter (of type com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLOutputFactoryImpl$XMLStreamWriterProxy) does not implement Stax2 API natively and is missing method 'writeRaw': this breaks functionality such as indentation that relies on it. You need to upgrade to using compliant Stax implementation like Woodstox or Aalto